# Random Forests in R - Feature extraction method?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, feature-extraction

I'm working on a university project where I need to build a Random Forests model in R to predict if patients have depressive tendencies according to their EEG-data. I already preprocessed the data and built a general model for the forest. Currently, I'm fine-tuning it to receive the best possible prediction Accuracy. If I understand that correctly, I need to do some Feature Extraction (At this moment, I have 1584 Features) and tuning of the hyperparameters. But I'm not sure how to perform the Feature Extraction in R? Right now, I'm doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(eegkit)
library(rlist)
library(edfReader)
library(eegUtils)
library(e1071)
library(ggplot2)

yourdata_neu <- data.frame(df_test)
rownames(yourdata_neu) <- NULL

set.seed(42)
###############################Random Forest
for (t in 1:10) {
seed <- sample.int(10)
set.seed(seed)  
  seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 50)
  for(i in 1:50){
  seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, 12)}
  
  ## For the last model:
  seeds[[50]] <- sample.int(1000, 1)
    
yourdata_neu$Depressiv <- as.factor(yourdata_neu$Depressiv)

inTraining <- createDataPartition(yourdata_neu$Depressiv[1:nrow(yourdata_neu)], p = 0.70, list = FALSE)
training <- yourdata_neu[inTraining,] 
testing <- yourdata_neu[-inTraining,]

train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, verboseIter = TRUE, seeds = seeds) 

model <- train(training[,1:ncol(yourdata_neu)-1],as.factor(training[,ncol(yourdata_neu)]), method = "rf", type="classification", metric= "Accuracy", maximize= TRUE, trControl = train_control, importance = TRUE) 

prediction2 <- predict(model, testing[,1:ncol(yourdata_neu)-1])

confusionMatrix(prediction2, as.factor(testing[,ncol(yourdata_neu)]),  positive = "1") 

model1 <- randomForest(training[,1:ncol(yourdata_neu)-1],as.factor(training[,ncol(yourdata_neu)]), 
type="classification", importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE) 

prediction1 <- predict(model1, testing[,1:ncol(yourdata_neu)-1])
print(confusionMatrix(prediction1, as.factor(testing[,ncol(yourdata_neu)]),  positive = "1"))

Adding_columns <- NULL
varImp2 <- varImp(model, scale = TRUE)
Adding_columns <- t(varImp2$importance)
rownames(Adding_columns) <- paste0(rownames(Adding_columns),".", t)
Importance_Table <- rbind(Importance_Table, Adding_columns)
}

Importance_Table_Mean <- t(apply(Importance_Table, MARGIN = 2, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
Importance_Table_Filter <- as.data.frame(Importance_Table_Mean)
Importance_Table_Filter <- Importance_Table_Filter[,Importance_Table_Filter< 50]
Importance_Table_Filter <- colnames(Importance_Table_Filter) 
Excluding_Channels <- names(yourdata_neu) %in% Importance_Table_Filter
yourdata_neu <- yourdata_neu[!Excluding_Channels]
```

1. Run the randomForest 10 times and save each time the importance of every feature in the data frame "Importance_Table"
2. Calculating the mean of the 10 trials for each feature in "Importance_Table_Mean"
3. Use the data frame "Importance_Table_Filter" to save all features with an importance value of under 50 (50 was chosen by me)
4. Get the colnames(feature names) of the data frame "Importance_Table_Filter" and save them in the variable "Excluding_Channels"
5. Dropping all channels with an importance value of under 50 from my data set (yourdata_neu) and keeping the ones with more than 50.

But I get the feeling that this isn't a good approach and very subjective.
Does anybody have an idea to improve my model? My idea was to perform the Feature Extraction first and then optimizing the hyperparameters. It that common or advised to do it like this? I'm grateful for every input :)

**EDIT**: My specific problem is: I have a way to filter the variables according to their importance. But this approach seems to be very subjective and not quite logical. And my Accuracy varies after every iteration (mostly it stays between 75% - 83% of an Accuracy. But it still takes huge leaps and sometimes falls into values of 58% or 91%.). So my question is if my approach is valid to extract features? Because after extracting the features the changes in Accrucacy are not quite linear (like instead of simply decreasing or increasing, it jumps around after every iteration of the for-loop)?

CSV of my dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k02hyqU51cAy5ka1gs5Ydr5_gOM5vTew/view?usp=sharing
(The last column is my prediction class (0 - Non_Depressive, 1 - Depressive) (All other columns are the EEG Channels, sliced by 99 to have a finer look at their frequency bands. All of these 99 instances are ranges (0 - 0.5, 0.5-1, 1-1.5....))

Adding the results of the model:

**Confusion Matrix and Accuracy (Currently 43 rows with 224 Features)**

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction 0 1
         0 4 1
         1 2 5
                                          
               Accuracy : 0.75            
                 95% CI : (0.4281, 0.9451)
    No Information Rate : 0.5             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.073           
                                          
                  Kappa : 0.5             
                                          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.000           
                                          
            Sensitivity : 0.8333          
            Specificity : 0.6667          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7143          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8000          
             Prevalence : 0.5000          
         Detection Rate : 0.4167          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5833          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7500          
                                          
       'Positive' Class : 1
```

**Variable Importance by Rank**

```
               Not_Depressive Depressive
FP1._.2...2.5    0.394776451  0.394776451
FP1._.4.5...5   -0.815542331 -0.815542331
FP1._.10...10.5 -0.370450874 -0.370450874
FP1._.12.5...13  0.334105732  0.334105732
FP1._.13.5...14 -0.340685260 -0.340685260
FP1._.17...17.5 -0.501003010 -0.501003010
FP1._.22.5...23 -0.622285092 -0.622285092
FP1._.24...24.5  0.855743225  0.855743225
FP1._.26...26.5  0.088306484  0.088306484
FP1._.31...31.5  0.673248466  0.673248466
FP1._.38.5...39  0.858185451  0.858185451
FP1._.40...40.5 -0.367230334 -0.367230334
FP1._.43...43.5  1.416965591  1.416965591
FP2._.1...1.5    0.306914159  0.306914159
FP2._.14.5...15  0.212468281  0.212468281
FP2._.15...15.5  0.660034859  0.660034859
FP2._.16.5...17  0.534253983  0.534253983
FP2._.17...17.5  0.000000000  0.000000000
FP2._.20.5...21 -0.692894470 -0.692894470
FP2._.22.5...23 -0.453966134 -0.453966134
FP2._.26...26.5  0.086515835  0.086515835
FP2._.37...37.5 -0.277306716 -0.277306716
FP2._.47...47.5  0.501003010  0.501003010
FP2._.48...48.5  0.589315133  0.589315133
F7._.7.5...8    -0.517957193 -0.517957193
F7._.11.5...12   0.888994305  0.888994305
F7._.16.5...17  -1.210955303 -1.210955303
F7._.41.5...42   0.709952293  0.709952293
F3._.0.5...1     1.086024943  1.086024943
F3._.2...2.5    -1.405791664 -1.405791664
F3._.3...3.5    -1.036833331 -1.036833331
F3._.3.5...4    -0.990354581 -0.990354581
F3._.5...5.5     0.000000000  0.000000000
F3._.6.5...7     1.192633280  1.192633280
F3._.10.5...11  -0.175450100 -0.175450100
F3._.12.5...13  -0.555236901 -0.555236901
F3._.13.5...14   0.728840752  0.728840752
F3._.24...24.5  -0.011624739 -0.011624739
F3._.24.5...25   0.762078219  0.762078219
F3._.26...26.5  -0.065963276 -0.065963276
F3._.35.5...36   0.687106655  0.687106655
F3._.36.5...37   0.724699304  0.724699304
F3._.38...38.5   0.331404195  0.331404195
F3._.38.5...39  -0.277306716 -0.277306716
F3._.39.5...40   0.673248466  0.673248466
F3._.40...40.5   2.020212240  2.020212240
F3._.41.5...42  -0.641137162 -0.641137162
F3._.43...43.5  -0.501003010 -0.501003010
F3._.46.5...47  -0.501003010 -0.501003010
F3._.47...47.5   0.599329127  0.599329127
F3._.49.5...50   1.097301169  1.097301169
FZ._.2...2.5     0.709952293  0.709952293
FZ._.2.5...3     0.856209545  0.856209545
FZ._.4...4.5     0.714930331  0.714930331
FZ._.7...7.5    -0.177233514 -0.177233514
FZ._.28.5...29   1.417796622  1.417796622
FZ._.31...31.5   0.977566867  0.977566867
FZ._.33...33.5   0.116260208  0.116260208
FZ._.35...35.5   0.000000000  0.000000000
FZ._.37...37.5   0.184521958  0.184521958
FZ._.37.5...38   0.000000000  0.000000000
FZ._.38...38.5   0.000000000  0.000000000
FZ._.40...40.5   0.501003010  0.501003010
FZ._.43.5...44   1.535276325  1.535276325
FZ._.49.5...50  -1.178166964 -1.178166964
F4._.0.5...1    -0.188658932 -0.188658932
F4._.1...1.5     1.647141911  1.647141911
F4._.1.5...2     1.364878736  1.364878736
F4._.2.5...3     0.501003010  0.501003010
F4._.3...3.5     0.747236837  0.747236837
F4._.3.5...4    -1.306683384 -1.306683384
F4._.5...5.5    -0.199213312 -0.199213312
F4._.6.5...7     0.579093700  0.579093700
F4._.15...15.5   0.103645533  0.103645533
F8._.2...2.5    -0.292933032 -0.292933032
F8._.4...4.5     0.501003010  0.501003010
F8._.5...5.5    -0.319746239 -0.319746239
F8._.7.5...8    -0.922073108 -0.922073108
F8._.13...13.5   0.000000000  0.000000000
F8._.14.5...15  -0.541663506 -0.541663506
F8._.17...17.5   0.000000000  0.000000000
F8._.17.5...18   0.501003010  0.501003010
F8._.19.5...20   0.222599721  0.222599721
F8._.20...20.5   0.245875307  0.245875307
F8._.21...21.5   0.206168939  0.206168939
F8._.21.5...22   1.002006020  1.002006020
F8._.27.5...28   0.266639453  0.266639453
F8._.28...28.5   0.791585765  0.791585765
F8._.28.5...29   0.501003010  0.501003010
F8._.29.5...30   0.362306621  0.362306621
F8._.37...37.5   0.445749157  0.445749157
F8._.37.5...38  -0.501003010 -0.501003010
F8._.40...40.5   1.221447122  1.221447122
F8._.40.5...41   0.436768478  0.436768478
F8._.43.5...44   1.238882969  1.238882969
F8._.44.5...45   1.714275955  1.714275955
F8._.48...48.5  -0.059362851 -0.059362851
AFZ._.1.5...2    0.384742802  0.384742802
AFZ._.2.5...3    1.197060568  1.197060568
AFZ._.9.5...10   1.203763251  1.203763251
AFZ._.24...24.5 -1.213853807 -1.213853807
AFZ._.28...28.5  0.459479697  0.459479697
AFZ._.31.5...32 -1.040439158 -1.040439158
AFZ._.33.5...34 -0.329464058 -0.329464058
AFZ._.47...47.5  0.420148380  0.420148380
AFZ._.49...49.5  1.210955303  1.210955303
AF7._.0.5...1    0.005142873  0.005142873
AF7._.1...1.5   -1.002006020 -1.002006020
AF7._.1.5...2   -0.027103954 -0.027103954
AF7._.3...3.5   -0.362306621 -0.362306621
AF7._.3.5...4   -0.369134651 -0.369134651
AF7._.8...8.5   -0.291557956 -0.291557956
AF7._.11...11.5 -0.302092945 -0.302092945
AF7._.13...13.5  0.134425409  0.134425409
AF7._.40.5...41  1.152308808  1.152308808
AF3._.3...3.5    0.501003010  0.501003010
AF3._.3.5...4   -0.122899636 -0.122899636
AF3._.6...6.5   -0.703960734 -0.703960734
AF3._.24.5...25 -0.285028577 -0.285028577
AF3._.35...35.5  0.893034457  0.893034457
AF3._.36.5...37  0.321920980  0.321920980
AF3._.37.5...38  0.000000000  0.000000000
AF3._.38...38.5  0.884053474  0.884053474
AF3._.38.5...39  1.408335582  1.408335582
AF3._.39...39.5  0.400851110  0.400851110
AF3._.39.5...40  1.143692072  1.143692072
AF3._.40.5...41  2.027085696  2.027085696
AF3._.41...41.5 -0.186103645 -0.186103645
AF3._.42...42.5  1.529849500  1.529849500
AF3._.42.5...43 -0.019252745 -0.019252745
AF3._.43...43.5 -0.198061209 -0.198061209
AF3._.43.5...44 -1.002006020 -1.002006020
AF3._.44...44.5 -0.300441301 -0.300441301
AF3._.44.5...45  1.002006020  1.002006020
AF3._.45...45.5  0.707844329  0.707844329
AF3._.45.5...46  1.227980053  1.227980053
AF3._.46...46.5  0.501003010  0.501003010
AF3._.46.5...47 -0.555236901 -0.555236901
AF3._.47...47.5  1.647744720  1.647744720
AF3._.48...48.5  1.334453452  1.334453452
AF3._.49...49.5  0.571365551  0.571365551
AF3._.49.5...50  0.000000000  0.000000000
AF4._.1.5...2    0.000000000  0.000000000
AF4._.2...2.5    0.525093901  0.525093901
AF4._.4...4.5    1.472221562  1.472221562
AF4._.5.5...6   -0.868233344 -0.868233344
AF4._.15...15.5  1.197060568  1.197060568
AF4._.28...28.5 -0.219644610 -0.219644610
AF4._.39.5...40 -0.688981283 -0.688981283
AF8._.0.5...1   -0.555236901 -0.555236901
AF8._.1...1.5   -0.160751590 -0.160751590
AF8._.2...2.5    0.501003010  0.501003010
AF8._.3...3.5   -0.966043842 -0.966043842
AF8._.5.5...6   -1.208847339 -1.208847339
AF8._.13.5...14 -0.786145963 -0.786145963
AF8._.15...15.5  0.365094144  0.365094144
AF8._.15.5...16  0.314123457  0.314123457
AF8._.16...16.5  0.160954675  0.160954675
AF8._.16.5...17  0.207364212  0.207364212
AF8._.17...17.5 -0.810257301 -0.810257301
AF8._.17.5...18  0.329464058  0.329464058
AF8._.18...18.5  0.000000000  0.000000000
AF8._.19...19.5 -1.268227729 -1.268227729
AF8._.19.5...20  0.345877919  0.345877919
AF8._.22...22.5  0.691630270  0.691630270
AF8._.22.5...23 -0.269387027 -0.269387027
AF8._.23.5...24 -0.208949283 -0.208949283
AF8._.24...24.5  1.471122902  1.471122902
AF8._.25...25.5  1.163066474  1.163066474
AF8._.25.5...26 -0.617981267 -0.617981267
AF8._.26.5...27  0.408148937  0.408148937
AF8._.28...28.5  0.660934154  0.660934154
AF8._.28.5...29  0.411540249  0.411540249
AF8._.29...29.5 -0.024902880 -0.024902880
AF8._.29.5...30 -0.738979053 -0.738979053
AF8._.30.5...31  0.070330343  0.070330343
AF8._.37.5...38  0.207509288  0.207509288
AF8._.39...39.5  0.493367448  0.493367448
AF8._.44...44.5  1.450630468  1.450630468
F5._.2...2.5    -1.453814559 -1.453814559
F5._.3...3.5     0.000000000  0.000000000
F5._.5...5.5     1.002006020  1.002006020
F5._.11.5...12   0.724699304  0.724699304
F5._.12...12.5   0.724699304  0.724699304
F5._.16...16.5  -0.706691079 -0.706691079
F5._.16.5...17   1.106642611  1.106642611
F5._.19...19.5  -0.532155862 -0.532155862
F5._.25...25.5   1.210955303  1.210955303
F5._.26.5...27  -0.835582587 -0.835582587
F5._.29...29.5   0.472361264  0.472361264
F5._.30.5...31   0.000000000  0.000000000
F5._.33.5...34   0.753879413  0.753879413
F5._.35...35.5   0.199213312  0.199213312
F1._.0.5...1     0.153027576  0.153027576
F1._.1...1.5    -0.233669520 -0.233669520
F1._.1.5...2     0.501003010  0.501003010
F1._.2.5...3     0.843777012  0.843777012
F1._.9...9.5    -0.684745163 -0.684745163
F1._.30...30.5  -0.087105828 -0.087105828
F1._.30.5...31  -0.709952293 -0.709952293
F1._.33...33.5  -1.174251476 -1.174251476
F1._.35.5...36   1.098012248  1.098012248
F1._.39.5...40  -0.428333631 -0.428333631
F1._.41...41.5   1.470021502  1.470021502
F1._.45.5...46  -0.700216322 -0.700216322
F1._.48.5...49   1.051505172  1.051505172
F2._.0.5...1     0.720994309  0.720994309
F2._.38...38.5  -0.069107193 -0.069107193
F2._.41.5...42   0.000000000  0.000000000
F2._.43.5...44  -0.103958621 -0.103958621
F2._.44...44.5   1.387505403  1.387505403
F2._.48.5...49   1.744259565  1.744259565
F6._.0.5...1     0.797292583  0.797292583
F6._.1...1.5     0.123741220  0.123741220
F6._.1.5...2     0.964115324  0.964115324
F6._.6.5...7    -0.970119651 -0.970119651
F6._.10.5...11   0.643870575  0.643870575
F6._.11...11.5  -0.004376952 -0.004376952
F6._.13.5...14  -0.896944760 -0.896944760
F6._.15.5...16  -0.501003010 -0.501003010
F6._.16...16.5   0.533962073  0.533962073
F6._.16.5...17  -1.002006020 -1.002006020
F6._.24.5...25  -0.158867161 -0.158867161
F6._.26.5...27  -0.456823114 -0.456823114
F6._.30...30.5   1.522047602  1.522047602
F6._.30.5...31  -0.446769119 -0.446769119
F6._.39.5...40  -0.054233891 -0.054233891
F6._.47...47.5   0.358083187  0.358083187
```

Comment: Hey Ruffybeo, your question is really broad and it's would help if you narrow it down to a specific problem or question you are facing. Also, it's hard to comment on the model without seeing the results or the data right?

Comment: I can only give a few suggestions I can see off-hand, 1. if you do varImp with scale=TRUE, this will depend on the variables in the model, so it's not very clear what this mean of relative importance means.. 2. are any of your 1584 variables correlated? Maybe think about removing the redundancies ? 3. How much does the accuracy changes with your current filtering?

Comment: One thing you could try out is testing whether your variables can predict better than random values, using importance p values from ranger, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.11.2/topics/importance_pvalues

Comment: Hi StupidWolf, thank you so much for your comments! I edited my post with more information, results and I tried to specify my question. Sorry that I didn't specify it before

Comment: In terms of correlation: Some of them are correlating with each other, but it's quite hard for me to identify the redundancies here (For example FP1_0-0.5hz and FP2_0-0.5hz are correlating strong. But I don't know if they only correlating because they are on the same frequency length/band or if there are other reasons? Because every other channel with "0-0.5hz" is also correlating with the both of them)

Comment: Currently, my accuracy stays between 75 - 83%. But on some iterations, it drops down to 58% or jumps up to 91%, so I'm not quite sure if I extract the right features?

Comment: I'll definitely try out the importance p values from ranger, thank you so much for your suggestions!